# css apply rule only for specific section

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am learning CSS and facing a issue while applying the style rule for "a" tag. I have a navigation containing unordered list containing list items which contains  link. On hovering on the "li" tag, I want to change the color of the text inside the "a"tag. The below is the code I added for applying the css rule.

```
#top-nav ul >li:hover a{
color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

But this rule is applied to all the Links on the page. How can I ensure that the rule applies to all the direct links within the #top-nav ul > li and not all the child elements under #top-nav ul > li

Currently the above rule is being applied to #top-nav ul>li and li elements deep inside the div tag under the li tag

Answer (score 2):

Add a direct descendant selector after hover.

```
#top-nav ul > li:hover > a
```